# Angular - How to make a get request to an api to retrieve products?

Tags: angularjs, api, get

I want to display products and need to make a get request by connecting to an api (using a token) in order to get products (to display) using angular. I dont really know 
how to do that, tried to do it like in angular's documentation but its not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://testing.com/page/go',
        config: {
            params: {
                token: "1234x.1234x",
            }
        }
    })
    .then(function(products) {
        products.data;
    })
    .then(function(allProducts) {
        $scope.products = allProducts;
    })
});
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="product in products"> {{product}} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: _"products.data;"_  does nothing. You may want to add a return statement.

Comment: if I return products.data, nothing happens as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have two `then`s, and you're not storing products.data anywhere, so you could use them. Try this code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://testing.com/page/go',
        config: {
            params: {
                token: "1234x.1234x",
            }
        }
    })
    .then(function(products) {
        $scope.products = products.data;
    })
});
```

If you were checking angular http documentation, there are never 2 `then`s, but one with 2 arguments, first one for success, 2nd for failure.

```
$http(req).then(function(resp){...}, function(err){...});
```

Comment: Thank you. I had 2 then because I kinda thought I would have to first return the data and then assign it to $scope.products..but I guess I dont have to. I tried your code and it doesnt work as well. When I connect to an api requesting data, is there anything else I need to do besides the http get request? Im getting this error: Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"status":"error","message":"Token missing","errorNo":1000}